# HTTP POST using ESP8266 to PHP file URL in localhost

Tags: php, http, post, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I'm trying to do a POST request from my ESP8266 and send two variable values through URL. The POST request I have is shown below.

```cpp
client.print(String("POST ") + url + 
     " HTTP/1.1\r\n" + "Host: " +
      host + "\r\n" + "User-Agent: Arduino/1.0\r\n" + "Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n" + 
      "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" + "\r\n" + "Connection: close\r\n\r\n" +
      "Content-Length: " +  post.length() + "\r\n" +  post );
```

The POST data is like this.

```cpp
String post = "number=1&status=OFF";
```

I'm using XAMPP to host the webpage. Everything seems to work fine, but after execution what I receive is this on the PHP page.

> Notice: Undefined index: number in C:\xampp\htdocs\pumpupdate.php on
>   line 3
>
> Notice: Undefined index: status in C:\xampp\htdocs\pumpupdate.php on
>   line 4

Which means that the `$_GET` arguments in the PHP script aren't retrieved from the variables sent to the page's URL. When I tried to manually update the URL, it worked fine, to which I concluded that the PHP file works properly.

Please advise.

Comment: Is the php server running in localhost?

Comment: So, why do you handling post req at php side  with $get? Is not there a $post?

Comment: Yes it runs in local host. And yes I used $GET. But still the variable values are not been assigned.

Comment: Get method passes the variables to the url. So, it is not the method u use. So i mean retrieve the parameters with $_POST.

Comment: Arguments from the URL (`example.com?number=1&status=OFF`) are put into `$_GET`, arguments from the body of the POST request (this is what you have) are put into `$_POST`.

Comment: Put two `\r\n`s fter the Content-Length header, to make a blank line. You have them after the Connection: Close. A good tool for testing POSTs is [Postman](http://www.getpostman.com)

Comment: And only one `\r\n` after `Connection: close`.